# Android how to set custom activity label according to info from EditText?

Tags: android, label, title

As the titles says, I want to change the label/title of the activity according to some text entered in an `EditText`. How could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setTitle(Text);
```

put this line in the button listener to change the Activity Title.